# php apache unknow 500 error

Tags: apache-2.2, php, centos

I currently have an error with my apache/php installation on a centos system. I checked the log files in /var/log/httpd and in my logs directory as specified in my virtual host file, but they are not getting populated with errors. I've also set php to log errors, through the php.ini, to the /var/log/httpd/ but the error file is not getting created. When I setup the display_errors = On in the php.ini all I get is a blank screen.

this is a git controlled project that is running off of an ubuntu server that works perfectly, so there is something missing from this server.

My question is, is there any way I can get more info on the error that I am getting? I just need something that I can trace back. I am using a codeigniter framework, so for me to trace through the code will take days.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a new installation? Are the error-log directories writeable for the Apache-user?

Answer (score 0):

I once had this problem when I enabled mpm_worker in /etc/sysconfig/httpd on a RHEL box. All logs were also empty